# How to make streaming sql in spring jdbc template?

Tags: java, sql, spring, java-8, jdbctemplate

We have a sql in spring jdbc template fetching millions of records, which we want to process in Java.. Any way to do the same using less memory?

Comment: Could you provide some code showing what you are doing right now and what you want to ehance?

Comment: For example use [JDBCTemplate#query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler-) method which takes a [RowCallbackHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) as the argument. RowCallbackHandler is called for each row. You can process row-by-row instead fetching all results into memory.

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/71443-streaming-resultset-and-jdbctemplate

Comment: Not exactly with jdbcTemplate, but this is one way to do in spring- https://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html. And this too- http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2012/02/mysql-jdbc-driver-and-streaming-large.html

Comment: The JDBC drivers for most relational databases don't support streaming now, but that might change with reactive Java.

Comment: Currently, what we do is fetch the millions of rows from database and insert the result into a temp table, with a column for serial number.. ... From java code, we prepare sql to picks chunks of say 10000 rows from this temp table using the serial number ... And proceed with processing that chunk...

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in:

[`JdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(int fetchSize)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize(int))

From the docs:

> Set the fetch size for this JdbcTemplate. This is important for
>   processing large result sets: Setting this higher than the default
>   value will increase processing speed at the cost of memory
>   consumption; setting this lower can avoid transferring row data that
>   will never be read by the application.
>
> Default is 0, indicating to use the JDBC driver's default.

Comment: Is it possible to process the data which is received after SQL fetches for one "FetchSize" and then sql continues with another chunk, which we process in another cycle.?

Comment: @VijayKumarChauhan This method doesn't manage how your SQL server is going the handle the query, rather than by how many rows you are going to process your total rows.

Comment: Exactly... Now you understood the issue... We are looking for streaming sql... Pick few of the millions and then process.